# .NET Runtime Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, interface

Could someone please explain what's the difference between inheriting from `ISerializable` interface and declaring your object as `[Serializable]`?

*I know that in the first case you are have to implement the `ISerializable` interface members, while in the second case this work is likely to be done by the C# itself.*

But what doesn't make sense to me then is the following behavior:

```
public void Foo<T>() where T : ISerializable
{
   // Whatever
}
```

Now, if I have some class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Value
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

*And unfortunately I can't call my `X.Foo<Value>()`, because the compiler says:*

```
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Value' to 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable'
```

---

**I'm pretty sure it's my misunderstanding of something obvious, so please point out what am I doing wrong.**

---

### UPDATE (IMPORTANT :)

*How do I make the `where T : ISerializable` statement work with `[Serializable]` class too? Is there a way?*

What I'm trying to achieve is the compilation-time error if the supplied type `T` is not serializable (by using `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable` way).

***Obviously, my current check handles only the second case, so how do I make it handle both of them?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Serializable` is merely an attribute you place on a class to let classes such as `SoapFormatter` know (via reflection) it can be serialized. Decorating a class with an attribute **does not** make a class implement an interface, which is why the compiler complains in your case. If memory serves, one implements `ISerializable` if one wants more control over the serialization process.

Comment: Are you sure that XmlSerializer uses this attribute?

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay I'm pretty sure you can't. Attributes are runtime entities, not compile time.

Comment: @Rohan West - Thanks for pointing that out, it appears it doesn't. I altered the example class I gave, but the crux of the answer remains.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your update: there is no way you can put a generic constraint on the presence of an attribute.

The next best thing you can do is throw an exception (obviously at runtime, not at compile-time). For a generic method, it would look something like this:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
    if (!typeof (ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (T))
        || !typeof (T).GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<SerializableAttribute>().Any())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Type {0} is not serializable.", typeof (T).FullName));
    }
}
```

For a generic class, you could do this in the static constructor (fails faster):

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    static Foo()
    {
        if (!typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
            || !typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<SerializableAttribute>().Any())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Type {0} is not serializable.", typeof(T).FullName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Although would better leave the `T` unchecked, because attempt to serialize any type which doesn't support it would raise an exception anyway (although not so fast). **But still, shouldn't this type of check be simple?** It seems to me, that this can be considered a *common task* in `C#`... Or not so many people use the `where`-based checking nowadays?

Answer (score 2):

`[Serializable]` is just an attribute. It doesn't make your class implement the ISerializable interface. All it does it indicate to the .NET framework that your class can be serialized.

So when you attempt to serialize your class, the framework will check how it should do so. If there is no ISerializable interface, it will attempt to use the built-in serializers and take care of it for you. If you explicitly implemented ISerializable, then it'll use your custom serialization implementation.

This is why sometimes you have to write classes like

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : ISerializable
{}
```

Unfortunately you cannot do what you want and achieve compile-time checking for either `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`. The best you can do is a run-time check inside the method whether the type passed in is serializable or not (either through reflection or by catching a serialization exception).

Alternatively, you could adopt a convention that all your serializable types must implement your own version of ISerializable:

```
public interface ICanBeSerialized
{
    // this interface is left intentionally blank
}

public class Value : ICanBeSerialized
{
    // do whatever
}

public class MyClass 
{
    public void Foo<T>() where T : ICanBeSerialized
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute simple indicates that the class can be serialized. Implementing ISerailizable will override the serialization process. You class Value should implement the ISerializable interface.

```
public class Value : ISerializable 
{
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISerializeable` enables an object to create its own (de)serialization. You can use this to serialize deep data structures to a flattened version and recreate it when deserializing or when wanting to serialize specific structures to simple values (like `Color`).

In general, the inbuilt serialization process is sufficient, though.

Comment: Is there any way to make the statement `where T : ISerializable` work with simple `[Serializable]` objects

Comment: no, as classes marked with the `Serializable` attribute don't implement `ISerializable`.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to check if the supplied generic type `T` can be serialized *(using the .NET framework (`[Serializable]`) or using custom implementation provided)*? Obviously, this statement is done to result in a compile-time error if the type supplied can't be serialized.